# What is a LU session?

Tags: session

I am reading a book and I come across this name.  LU Session.

I know what a HTTP session is but what is LU session?

Can someone tell me what a LU session means?  How does it different from a normal session?

Thanks

Comment: What is the name of the book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you reading a book related to SNA?  If so, I think it is Logical Unit Session

A LU session (Logical Unit Session) is used to transmit information between SNA devices.  Logical Units need to be the same type because SNA information can only flow between likes LUs.